# get list of printer ports

Tags: c#, list, printing, ports

I'm looking for a way to list all printer ports on the current PC. I want to list them and put them into a combo box. I was going to create a list and pull that in every time the cbo must load, however I then thought about if people add their own ports and some printers install themselves to new ports. Because of this just stating a generic list of ports might not be the correct way.

I am using DOS print process to the printer port directly and in the settings need the user to select which port to print to.

I'm sure someone has a quick way, or a way they can point me to. I saw a couple ways online however It completely boggled my mind and I don't like using code I can't understand, and don't have the time to understand it right now unfortunately. I am sure there must be a class of somesort in C# already created to do this. Most of the other ways I saw to me appeared to be importing several dlls and or running through a few registeries.

And assistance is greatly appreciated

**UPDATE** just to be clear I want a way that will simply return to me LPT1 LPT2 COM1....

Comment: Sorry just to be clear a want a way that will simply return to me
LPT1
LPT2
COM1....

Comment: also TCP printer ports or just LPT and COM ?

Comment: TCP would be a good addition, but not necessarily needed